# How to get crash reason in Xcode Crash log system?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

I got a crash in my test flight version of an iOS application, but when I check the Xcode crash log system, I am getting the crashed line and crashed function name. But I was not able to find the reason of crash. Does anybody know how to find out the reason of the crash occurred?

Here is the screenshot of the crash log of Xcode -> Organiser.
[image]

From this I am not getting the crash reason.

Comment: Can you attack a screenshot of the crashed line?

Comment: to read the crash description you need to decrypt using .dSYM

Comment: Please find the screenshot of the crash log that I have added.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to show the report in Finder, as per https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devc8ced2ea3 by Control+Clicking in the list of crash reports on the left.

Please update your question with the `.crash` file, which should provide full information about the crash.

Answer (score 0):

The function that *actually* crashed is objc_msgSend. The most likely cause is that you sent a message to an object that had a different type than you and the compiler expected.